# Allocate a HTML file inside a section using Kotlin

Tags: android, html, kotlin

I made a HTML file and I located into **`/app/src/main/assets`**

and I'm trying to get the entire text but I got null from my app:

```
 try {
        val fileContent = this.javaClass.getResource("file:///android_asset/index.html")!!.readText()

        lblSection.text = HtmlCompat.fromHtml(fileContent, HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)
    }catch (exception: Exception){
        Log.d("error loading HTML", exception.message!!)
    }
```

I don't know where do I need to allocate my file to get read from my app.

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

`file:///android_asset/index.html` is a URL that you could use with `WebView`, but little else. It definitely will not work with Java's `getResource()`.

To read in an asset, retrieve an `AssetManager` from your `Activity` or other `Context` via `getAssets()`. Then, call `open()` on the `AssetManager`, with a relative path within `assets/` to your desired content (in your case, `getAssets().open("index.html")`). That will give you an `InputStream` from which you can read in the content.